# Switch from xHCI driver to EHCI on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, image-processing, linux-kernel, usb

I'm currently working on a project in a ubuntu 16.04 environment and a depth camera (an Asus Xtion Pro). The problem is that my camera is not working with the ubuntu's USB3.0 host controller xhci. So I'm trying to force the USB2 host controller ehci to manage my serial ports instead. But since my laptop only has 3.0 USB ports I cannot disable the XHCI Preboot mode through the BIOS. And thoose drivers being built in the kernel and not as modules I cannot just disactivate the xhci.

After some searchs on google, I found [this discussion](http://www.pcl-developers.org/xhci-hcd-I-hate-you-USB-3-0-and-Primesense-Asus-Xtion-td5707949.html) suggesting to build a kernel in which both the ehci and xhci drivers are built as modules so I could choose which one i'd like to use. The problem is that I'm a total newbie in kernel building...

I've found and unsuccessfully followed [this tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) to create a new kernel, but I have an error after editing the configuration with this command :

```
fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
```

The changes I've made were to switch the **xHCI HCD (USB 3.0) support** and **EHCI HCD (USB 2.0) support** options in *Device Drivers* -> *USB support*  from built-in to module. From what I understood from the terminal output, I cannot not build the xhci into the kernel. Here is the output :

```
check-config: /tmp/tmp.P1QuAGSbJX/CONFIGS/amd64-config.flavour.generic: loading config
check-config: /home/observator/kerneltestx/linux-hwe-4.10.0/debian.hwe/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<ensures USB 2.0/1.1 probe ordering> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<ensures USB 2.0/1.1 probe ordering> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD_PLATFORM policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'm', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'm'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<Don't use the generic ehci/ohci code on omap, it doesn't work> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: 70/73 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.P1QuAGSbJX/CONFIGS/amd64-config.flavour.lowlatency: loading config
check-config: /home/observator/kerneltestx/linux-hwe-4.10.0/debian.hwe/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<ensures USB 2.0/1.1 probe ordering> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD_PLATFORM policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'm', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'm'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<Don't use the generic ehci/ohci code on omap, it doesn't work> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<ensures USB 2.0/1.1 probe ordering> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: 70/73 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.P1QuAGSbJX/CONFIGS/i386-config.flavour.generic: loading config
check-config: /home/observator/kerneltestx/linux-hwe-4.10.0/debian.hwe/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<ensures USB 2.0/1.1 probe ordering> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<ensures USB 2.0/1.1 probe ordering> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD_PLATFORM policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'm', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'm'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<Don't use the generic ehci/ohci code on omap, it doesn't work> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: 70/73 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.P1QuAGSbJX/CONFIGS/i386-config.flavour.lowlatency: loading config
check-config: /home/observator/kerneltestx/linux-hwe-4.10.0/debian.hwe/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD_PLATFORM policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'm', 'armhf': 'n', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'm'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<Don't use the generic ehci/ohci code on omap, it doesn't work> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<ensures USB 2.0/1.1 probe ordering> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<ensures USB 2.0/1.1 probe ordering> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: 70/73 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.P1QuAGSbJX/CONFIGS/armhf-config.flavour.generic: loading config
check-config: /home/observator/kerneltestx/linux-hwe-4.10.0/debian.hwe/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<ensures USB 2.0/1.1 probe ordering> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<ensures USB 2.0/1.1 probe ordering> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: 71/73 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.P1QuAGSbJX/CONFIGS/armhf-config.flavour.generic-lpae: loading config
check-config: /home/observator/kerneltestx/linux-hwe-4.10.0/debian.hwe/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<ensures USB 2.0/1.1 probe ordering> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<ensures USB 2.0/1.1 probe ordering> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: 71/73 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.P1QuAGSbJX/CONFIGS/arm64-config.flavour.generic: loading config
check-config: /home/observator/kerneltestx/linux-hwe-4.10.0/debian.hwe/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<ensures USB 2.0/1.1 probe ordering> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<ensures USB 2.0/1.1 probe ordering> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: 71/73 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.P1QuAGSbJX/CONFIGS/ppc64el-config.flavour.generic: loading config
check-config: /home/observator/kerneltestx/linux-hwe-4.10.0/debian.hwe/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<ensures USB 2.0/1.1 probe ordering> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: FAIL (m != y): CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD policy<{'amd64': 'y', 'arm64': 'y', 'armhf': 'y', 'i386': 'y', 'ppc64el': 'y'}> mark<ENFORCED> note<ensures USB 2.0/1.1 probe ordering> flag<REVIEW>
check-config: 71/73 checks passed -- exit 1
check-config: /tmp/tmp.P1QuAGSbJX/CONFIGS/s390x-config.flavour.generic: loading config
check-config: /home/observator/kerneltestx/linux-hwe-4.10.0/debian.hwe/config/annotations loading annotations
check-config: 73/73 checks passed -- exit 0

*** ERROR: 8 config-check failures detected
```

So my question is how can I change my USB driver (with or without a kernel build) ?

(Or if someone has a solution to make the Asus Xtion Pro work with the xHCI drivers (note that it is the first version of it which does not accept the patch done at this purpose))

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Have you tried upgrading your camera firmware as described [here](http://www.pcl-developers.org/xhci-hcd-I-hate-you-USB-3-0-and-Primesense-Asus-Xtion-td5707949.html#a5709642) ?

Comment: Yes I did, but I didn't worked, I suspect it is because I have the older version of the camera and it is for its newer version :/